# Scroll UITableView Cell beyond table bounds

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview, cell

I have a UITableView with changing height.

I wanted in every cell selection to kind of get the 'focus' on it by moving it to the middle of the screen. The problem is to move the upper and lower cells in the table since they cannot scroll beyond the table upper and lower bounds. I'll also prefer to do this with animations..

Any suggestions?
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I created small example of how to achieve this:
https://github.com/vkozlovskyi/CenterCellExample

You just need to calculate scroll offset of UITableView, and and animate the change:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Get offset for cell
    CGFloat centerOffset = self.tableView.frame.size.height / 2 - self.tableView.rowHeight / 2;

    // Content offset
    CGFloat total = indexPath.row * self.tableView.rowHeight;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.3 animations:^{
        self.tableView.contentOffset = CGPointMake(0, total - centerOffset);
    }];
}
```

It works for all cells, upper and lower too.

Comment: but this only works for the middle cells, the upper and lower won't scroll bent the bounds..

Comment: I changed the answer, try this solution

Answer (score 1):

You can add extra space to the content of your table view using the *contentInset* property. Add extra space above and below your table view will allow your cells to scroll all the way to the middle of your table view.

```
UITableView * tableView = self.tableView ;
CGRect bounds = self.tableView.bounds ;
CGFloat extraSpaceNeeded = 0.5 * ( bounds.size.height - tableView.rowHeight ) ;
tableView.contentInset = (UIEdgeInsets){ .top = -extraSpaceNeeded, .bottom = -extraSpaceNeeded } ;
```

Now you can just use

```
[tableView scrollToRowAtIndexPath:indexPath
                 atScrollPosition:UITableViewScrollPositionMiddle 
                         animated:animated];
```